# Child Controls of custom control not rendering correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, render

I'm adding a couple of controls as a child controls of another custom control I've developed.  Here's where I add the child controls (a custom label and a generic span control):

```
    public static void AddLabel(this IExtendedControl control, string inheritableCssClass = "")
    {
        TestCLabel contentLabel = new TestCLabel();
        contentLabel.Text = control.LabelText;
        control.Controls.Add(contentLabel);
        if (control.Required)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl requiredFieldIndicator = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
            requiredFieldIndicator.Attributes["class"] = "requiredFieldIndicator";
            requiredFieldIndicator.InnerText = " *";
            control.Controls.Add(requiredFieldIndicator);
        }
```

and I then do the following in the render method of the parent control:

```
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter w)
    {
        base.Render(w);

        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            c.RenderControl(w);
        }

        if (Required)
        {
            rfv.RenderControl(w);
        }
    }
```

but I get the error 'An entry with the same key already exists'.  This is being caused by the attempt to manually render the child controls.  I don't think I should need to do the manual rendering, but before I coded this in the controls weren't appearing (nothing appears in the HTML markup).  Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Your issue likely stems from the fact that you are re-rendering all child controls after `base.Render()` has rendered the controls which would cause the duplicate key issue. At what stage in the life-cycle are you dynamically adding the controls?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the manual rendering of the child controls wasn't the issue.  I'd reworked the code
as I was originally assigning the child controls to a property of the parent control but changed this to add the child controls to the controls collection of the parent control (so that the child controls now go through their correct life cycle).  I'd previously been manually rendering the child controls when they were properties of the parent control and was still doing this.  When manually rendering all the children, the controls were being added a second time.  Still doesn't answer:

- Why is the manual adding necessary, as this should be automatic?

Comment: Is this an additional question or a solution?